# Simple calculator about keybinding

Tags: java, beginner

This is code for a simple calculator. Can someone review it, so I can know if there is something wrong? I also want to know if I can link a keybinding to a JButton so I don't have to write an `actionlistner` for a `JButton` `enterBut`. I already tested it several times and it works fine.

Also, someone told me yesterday that I shouldn't use a `foreach` loop to assign a value to my null `Button` array, and instead I need to use a `for` loop. Can someone explain why? Also, if there is a way to get rid all of the `if` statements in the `calculate` method, please tell me.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

class Window6 {
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JTextField screen = new JTextField();
    private final String[] numberText  = {"7","8","9","4","5","6","1","2","3","0",".","c"};
    private final String[] functionText = {"+", "-", "*", "/"};
    private final JButton numberButton[] = new JButton[numberText.length];
    private final JButton functionButton[] = new JButton[functionText.length];
    private JButton equalBut = new JButton("=");
    private JPanel numberPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel functionPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    public Window6() {
        JPanel temp = new JPanel();
        numberPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));
        functionPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        int index = 0;
        for(JButton x : functionButton) {
            x = new JButton();
            x.setText(functionText[index]);
            x.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JButton temp = (JButton)e.getSource();
                     screen.setText(screen.getText() + temp.getText());
                }
            });
            functionPanel.add(x);
            index++;

        }
        index =0;
        InputMap im = equalBut.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0, false), "submit");
        ActionMap ap = equalBut.getActionMap();
        ap.put("submit", new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                calculate();

            }


        });
        equalBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                calculate();
            }
        });

        for(JButton x : numberButton) {
            x = new JButton();
            x.setText(numberText[index]);
            x.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    JButton temp = (JButton)e.getSource();
                    if(!"c".equals(temp.getText())) {

                        screen.setText(screen.getText() + temp.getText());
                    } else {
                        screen.setText("");
                    }
                }
            });
            numberPanel.add(x);
                index++;
        }   
        temp.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        temp.add(this.functionPanel);
        temp.add(this.equalBut);
        screen.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,100));
        frame.add(screen, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        panel.add(numberPanel);
        panel.add(temp);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(300, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    private void calculate() {

        String str = screen.getText();
        String number[] = str.split("[+||\\-||*||/]");

        int index = number[0].length();
        String sign = str.substring(index, index + 1);

        System.out.println(sign);
        if ("-".equals(sign)) {
        try {
            float x = Float.parseFloat(number[0]);
            float y = Float.parseFloat(number[1]);
            screen.setText(String.valueOf(x - y));
        } catch (Exception e){
            screen.setText("Please enter numbers");
        }
        } else if ("+".equals(sign)) {
            try {
                float x = Float.parseFloat(number[0]);
                float y = Float.parseFloat(number[1]);
                screen.setText(String.valueOf(x + y));
            } catch (Exception e){
                screen.setText("Please enter numbers");
            }
        } else if ("*".equals(sign)) {
            try {
                float x = Float.parseFloat(number[0]);
                float y = Float.parseFloat(number[1]);
                screen.setText(String.valueOf(x * y));
            } catch (Exception e){
                screen.setText("Please enter numbers");
            }
        } else if ("/".equals(sign)) {
            try {
                float x = Float.parseFloat(number[0]);
                float y = Float.parseFloat(number[1]);
                screen.setText(String.valueOf(x / y));
            } catch (Exception e){
                screen.setText("Please enter numbers");
            }
        }

    }
}
public class hw6 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Window6();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to codereview.SE! Please take the [tour](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). E.g: *"I also want to know if I can link a keybinding to a JButton"* is aquestion for some other site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for sharing your code!

> [Is] there is a way to get rid all of the if statements in the calculate method?

This program lags a clear MVC hierarchy. This results in a somwhat procedural approach in the `calculate()` where you mix *business behavior* with access to *View elements*.

A proper OO approach would start with the  *function* buttons. The actions they trigger have the same *interface* (2 numbers input, one number output). But each of them causes a different calculation aka *different behavior*. In OOP *different behavior* means *different classes*:

```
interface CalculatorFunction{
   float caculate(float a, float b);
}

class FunctionAdd implements CalculatorFunction{
   float caculate(float summandA, float summandB){
     return summandA + summandB;
  }
}

class OperationFunction implements CalculatorFunction{
   float caculate(float minuend, float subtrahend){
     return minuend-subtrahend;
  }
}
// same for other functions
```

In your *Model*  layer you should create a variable holding an instance of this interface:

```
 privat static final CalculatorFunction NO_CALCULATION = (a,b)->throw new IlligelArgumentException("no operation selected");
 private CalculatorFunction function = NO_CALCULATION;
```

Having This you need to assign each function button its action individually:

```
 JButton buttonAdd = new JButton(new AbstractAction("+"){ 
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           function = new FunctionAdd();
           operandA = operandAccumilator; 
           operandAccumilator.clear();
        }
 });
 JButton buttonSubtract = new JButton(new AbstractAction("-"){ 
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           function = new FunctionSubtract();
           operandA = operandAccumilator; 
           operandAccumilator.clear();
        }
 });
// same for other functions
```

Obviosly this leads to some code duplication, so we extract the parts that change to *local variables*:

```
 String operator = "+";
 CalculatorFunction buttonFunction =  new FunctionAdd();
 JButton buttonAdd = new JButton(new AbstractAction(operator){ 
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           function = buttonFunction;
           operandA = operandAccumilator; 
           operandAccumilator.clear();
        }
 });
 operator = "-";
 buttonFunction =  new FunctionSubtract();
 JButton buttonAdd = new JButton(new AbstractAction(operator){ 
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           function = buttonFunction;
           operandA = operandAccumilator; 
           operandAccumilator.clear();
        }
 });
// same for other functions
```

now we can extract the identical repeated code into a *parameterized method*:

```
private JButton configureButton(String operator, CalculatorFunction buttonFunction){
 return new JButton(new AbstractAction(operator){ 
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           function = buttonFunction;
           operandA = operandAccumilator; 
           operandAccumilator.clear();
        }
   });
 }
```

and use that in the gui setup:

```
JButton buttonAdd = configureButton("+", new FunctionAdd());
JButton buttonSubtract = configureButton("-", new FunctionSubtract());
// same for other functions
```

In consequence the method `calculate` change to:

```
   try {
        float x = Float.parseFloat(number[0]);
        float y = Float.parseFloat(number[1]);            
        screen.setText(String.valueOf(function.caculate(x,y)));
    } catch (Exception e){
        screen.setText("Please enter numbers");
    }
```

That's all, no more code in `calculate` ...

---

> what‘s operandA and OperandAccumilator， I can't find it any where in your code – user7639356

These are (new) member variables. The Number buttons are expected to add individual digits to `operandAccumilator`.

---

> if I use keyboard then it wouldn't work, though. – user7639356

Neither would have your original code.

Either way you have to convert the user input (given by GUI or command line) into model data. Usually it is easier to do with an OO approach than with the procedural solution you came up with.

Comment: what‘s  operandA and OperandAccumilator， I can't find it any where  in your code

Comment: if I use keyboard then it wouldn't work, though.

Comment: my code does work with keyboard (look at the calculate() ),  and I still doesn't understand the part about operaaxdaccumilator and OperaA, I  can't find anywhere you initialize and declare that variable

Comment: *"I still doesn't understand the part about operaaxdaccumilator and OperaA, I can't find anywhere you initialize and declare that variable"* This is because I did not. I assumed you where able to anticipate that.